# Filing mistake when converting from c to c++

Tags: c++, c, file-handling

The problem im having is that i wrote a code in c for filing for my program and when i wrote the same code in c++ it wasn't working. Please help me find out the mistake i'm making while writing the code in c++.

C Code :

```
FILE* dict = fopen("small.txt", "r");
char word[MAX_LINE];
Node* root = newNode(); // pointer to main root of Trie
Node* temp;
while (fgets(word, MAX_LINE, dict) != NULL) {
      temp = root;
    buildTrie(temp, word);
}
fclose(dict);
```

C++ Code :

```
ifstream infile;
char word[MAX_LINE];
Node* root = newNode(); // pointer to main root of Trie
Node* temp;

infile.open("small.txt");
while(infile)
{
  for(int i =0;i<MAX_LINE;i++)
  {
      infile>>word[i];
      temp = root;
    buildTrie(temp, word);

  }
}
infile.close();
```

Comment: The second reads character by character, the first one doesn't.

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. "Doesn't work" is never a good problem description. Describe the input, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: It doesnt make a trie structure properly if use the c++ code while it works perfectly fine for the C code.

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing code like this in C++, I'd probably write something more like this:

```
std::string word;

while (std::getline(infile, word))
    buildTrie(temp, word);
```

In all honesty, I doubt I'd write code exactly like that either though--I'd probably wrap the `trie` up into a class, so the code would look more like:

```
Trie t;
std::string word;

while std::getline(infile, word))
    t.add(word);
```

Comment: Its character array not a string. Now what?

Comment: `word.c_str()` may help you there. You'll have to tweak `buildTrie` to take `const char *` if it doesn't already.

Comment: @user4581301: No. Tweak (or overload) `buildTrie` to take a `std::string const &`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using char arrays and c-strings use [`istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to read as in your c programme:

```
infile.open("small.txt");
while(infile.getline(word, MAX_LINE) )
{
    temp = root;
    buildTrie(temp, word);
}
infile.close();
```

Be carefull to loop on the read operation.

Now depending on the rest of your code,  you could also consider to migrate from `char[]` to `string`.  This has lots of advantages and is more in the c++ philosophy.   You can then use [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) as suggested by Jerry in his answer.

Comment: Looking at your C code,  the part that you've displayed should work as it should.  A simple verification would be to display word instead of calling buildTree():  the display should be the same.  I assume the problem is in buildTrie (or even newNode() if you've kept some malloc() ).  You have to post more code to get more help.